# Perform PCA in python on audio data

Tags: python, audio, feature-detection, deep-learning

I'm trying to pre-process some audio-data to use it for some feature learning algorithm. Does it make sense to perform the PCA directly on the magnitude spectrum of a STFT or FFT or do I need a step in between? I saw that for images the data matrix is often flattened before PCA.

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
from scipy import signal
from scipy.fftpack import fft
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab

# Read file to get samplerate and numpy array containing the signal 
(fs, x) = read("../someaudio.wav")


channels = [
    np.array(x[:, 0]),
    np.array(x[:, 1])
]

# Combine channels to make a mono signal out of stereo
channel =  np.mean(channels, axis=0)

# Generate spectrogram 
## Freqs is the same with different songs, t differs slightly
Pxx, freqs, t, plot = pylab.specgram(
    channel,
    NFFT=2048, 
    Fs=44100, 
    detrend=pylab.detrend_none,
    window=pylab.window_hanning,
    noverlap=int(2048 * 0.5))
```

Suppose I build a dataset of multiple of those spectrums (Pxx). Can I apply PCA directly on it or is there another step (like flattening) necessary?

Thanks!